# overheating dell inspiron n5010

Tags: overheating, fancontrol

I have a DELL inspiron n5010 laptop with Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit OS, the only problem I have is the overheating of my CPU.

I think that this is related to the usage of the CPU fan. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

install bumblebee it will solve the problemwith the GPU drivers  worked for me  a few months ago on the same laptop https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation